# CiviCRM Entities module makes error 500 to site

Tags: drupal, civicrm-entity

I'm doing a drupal installation 7.56 with CiviCRM. When I install the CIVICrm Entity module the site starts getting error 500.
DOes anyone knows what to do?

best regards 
Eduardo Catarino

Comment: Can you look in the php error log and see if any errors? Need more information to work with

Comment: [This answer on how to see PHP errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/43034) might come in handy Eduardo, then the source of the problem will be much clearer for you to report or debug.

Answer (score 1):

Hi to all and thanks for the ones that gave some clues that helped me to solve the problem.

I was using the drupal and CIVICRM with 2 diferent databases. For that reason after installing the CIVICrm entity module everithing seem not to work.

I checked the civicrm bitnami installation and realized that it was working only with one comon database.

I'm able advance with the project.

Best regards
Eduardo

Comment: So with CiviCRM tables in the same database as Drupal, CiviCRM Entity chokes on install?  I'll have to take a look at that... Thanks for reporting this.